# TypeError: type object 'State' has no attribute 'S'

Tags: python

I'm working on the following model for simulating epidemics in python (fitting for the current situation). 
This is the code I'm working on:

```
import modsim
tc = 3 #time between contacts
tr = 4 #time between recoveries

cr = 1/tc #contact rate per day(beta)
rr = 1/tr #recovery rate per day(gamma)

S = 89
I = 1
R = 0

t0 = 0
t_end = 7*14

class State:
    def __init__(self, S, I, R):
        self.S = S
        self.I = I
        self.R = R

class System:
    def __init__(self, init, t0, t_end, cr, rr):
        self.init = init
        self.t0 = t0
        self.t_end = t_end
        self.cr = cr
        self.rr = rr



def update_func(state, t, system):
    s = state.S
    i = state.I
    r = state.R

    infected = system.cr * i * s
    recovered = system.rr * i

    s -= infected
    i += infected - recovered
    r += recovered
    l1=[s,i,r]
    x=0
    for attr, value in state.__dict__.items():
        setattr(state, attr, l1[x])
        x+=1

    return State

def run_sim(system, update_func):
    state = system.init
    for t in range(system.t0, system.t_end):
        state = update_func(state, t, system)

    return state

#driver code
state = State(89, 1, 0)
init = State(89, 1, 0)
sum = 0
for attr, value in init.__dict__.items():
    sum += value

for attr, value in init.__dict__.items():
    new_val = value/sum
    setattr(init, attr, new_val)

system = System(init, t0, t_end, cr, rr)
final_state = run_sim(system, update_func)
print(final_state)
```

However whenever I run the program I get:

```
AttributeError: type object 'State' has no attribute 'S'
```

I'm not really sure about what I'm doing wrong. The problem arises because the init object, when given as a value to the System class object, loses all of it's attributes and properties, leading to this error in the update_func function.

Comment: Could you share please the full traceback? Btw I don't understand why you pass the `update_func` as an argument to `run_sim` instead of calling it directly

Comment: In `update_func` you return the class (type) `State`, and not the `State` instance - `state`...

Comment: The funny thing is if we `print(state.S)` it prints the correct value but If we do `i = state.S` it says no attribute.. hmmm intresting.. however your code can be improved ALOT

Comment: Yea imma amature and have just been learning so my code's kinda shabby..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you return `State` (the class, which has no attribute `S`) instead of `state` (the object) from `update_func`.

Comment: Got it...but now when I try iterating from the state object after the run_sim function, I get a type error "Cannot unpack non iterable int object"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
return State
```

This loop got execute once:

```py
for t in range(system.t0, system.t_end):
        state = update_func(state, t, system)
```

Now, `update_func` returns `State` (class) not `state` (object). So when loop goes to second iteration you are actually passing `State` not `state` to state variable, hence it says:

```
AttributeError: type object 'State' has no attribute 'S'
```